# JavaFX absolute position layout but allow some child grow with parent

Tags: java, swing, javafx

we are migrating our app from Swing to JavaFX. We have thin client and server. The server tells client which component are in each screen, **their default x, y, width, height, data**... So they are created on the run. No predefined .fxml. Each screen is compound of several separate frames and inside these frames it behaves the same as outside. **Some components (frames and inner parts) are allowed to grow (in vertical, horizontal or both direction) if user resize the screen**. It can be any component (table - mainly, separator, textfield..). See example:

[image]
[image]

Can any layout from JavaFX handle this out of box? I have spend days trying to find any solution but was unable to perfect combination. In Swing we had our custom layoutmanager to handle this. So we have to make our own again in JFX? Thank you

**EDIT (more detailed explanation requested by @c0der):**

We have scene. In scene there is main content (say `MainPanel`) with inner dynamic content based on what user selected to run. The `MainPanel` use as max space as possible, so when user resize windows it automatically grows. In `MainPanel` we can have 1 or more `Panel`. In `Panel` we have 1 or more Components (`TableView, TextField, Separator..`). Every `Panel` or inner `Component` has x, y, width, heigh + boolean if it can be horizontaly/vertically scalled. If no `Panel` or `Component` have hor./ver. scale than it is absolute layout - they do not resize even if user change windows size. If any `Panel` or `Component` have hor./ver. scale it can grow inside own parent as max as possible (parent width and height) and other components are being pushed away but not outside of parent (like flow pane pushes away other components).

1. Component `Resizable table` (x=1, y=1, width=120, height=120, verticalScale=true, horizontalScale=true)
2. Component `Separator` - vertical (x=130, y=1, width=1, height=300, verticalScale=true, horizontalScale=false)
3. Component `Separator` - horizontal (x=1, y=150, width=150, height=1, verticalScale=false, horizontalScale=true)
4. Component `Static table` - right (x=150, y=10, width=130, height=180, verticalScale=false, horizontalScale=false)
5. Component `Static table` - bottom (x=1, y=155, width=140, height=160, verticalScale=false, horizontalScale=false)

Comment: I don't think you'll find any singular layout that does what you want in core JavaFX. But before you go creating your own custom layout you should consider trying a combination of existing layouts. For instance, your left side could be a `VBox` with appropriate configurations of `vgrow` and min/pref/max width/height of the children (i.e. tables). The outermost layout could maybe be an `HBox` or `SplitPane`.

Comment: @Slaw thank you. I have already tried many combinations. That is why I'm asking here. I don't know how many elements there can be in advace, or their position, width, height.. It can be one main resizable table or resizable table with bottom static table and so on. We have hundreds of screens and more and more are comming.

Comment: Please clarify what is the exact requirement of  the layout ? What is the input ? What is fixed ? What does change and in what range ? You need a definition regardless of the implementation, be it custom layout manager or a combination of standard layouts.

Comment: _In Swing we had our custom layoutmanager to handle this. So we have to make our own again in JFX?_ could well be .. and might even be the best solution. Before starting, I would try to learn all ins and outs of existing layouts, both core (my first go here would be on GridPane - just because it's a well-defined grid - with appropriate constraints) and external (did you try MigPane? or whatever its name in the fx world is). Happy coding :)

Comment: @kleopatra GridPane was very promissing, but after a lot of testing I figured out that I'm unable to make it work as I described. Thank you for the tip on "MigPane". I haven't heared about it.

Comment: Where did `GridPane` fail ? Consider posting mre to demonstrate it. Also I think the information in the post does not cover how are the `Panel`s layed out in the `MainPanel'.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using custom layout manager. For those who are interested in I solved it thanks to this: [AutoScalePane in JavaFX with layoutChildren()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732048/autoscalepane-in-javafx-with-layoutchildren) Using that post I created my custom layout manager which can solve everything accoring to my requirements.